# 1 minute of call costs 1 currency. Let's assume that duration of call has exponential distribution with a parameter $\lambda=1$

Tags: probability, expected-value, exponential-distribution

1 minute of call costs 1 currency. Let's assume that duration of call has exponential distribution with a parameter $\lambda=1$, which implies that call lasts for an avarage of 1 minute.

How much on avarage do we pay for a call?

$X$-Duration of call

$Z$-Costs of call

**My take on it:**

$$
\lambda=1\Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
P(X=t)=e^{-t}\\ 
P(X\leq t)=1-e^{-t}  
\end{matrix}\right.$$
$$
for$$ $$t\leq0$$

$$P(X=t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}=e^{-t},t>0$$

For call we pay $z$ currency $(z=1,2,...)$ if call lasts $z-1<X\leq z$

$$P(Z=z)=P(z-1<X\leq z)=(1-e^{-z})-(1-e^{-(z-1)})=e^{1-z}-e^{z}$$

**Avarage costs of call** $E(Z)$

$E(Z)=\sum_{z=1}^{\infty}z\times P(Z=z)=\sum_{z=1}^{\infty}z(e^{1-z}-e^{-z})=(e-1)\sum_{z=1}^{\infty}ze^{-z}=(e-1)\times \frac{e}{(e-1)^{2}}$

$\approx1.68$ currency

Could anyone check if it makes sense?

Comment: It's all correct except the last calculation: $(e-1) \times \frac{e}{(e-1)^2} = \frac{e}{e-1} \approx 1.58$, not $1.68$.

Comment: The mean duration is $1$ minute, so the mean cost is $1$.